# Make swift internal function unavailable for Test Target

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I want to create a function or convenience init of a class that can not be available for TestTarget when import with **@testable import**, I am not sure it's possible but looking for any way to restrict it.

```
class A {
   // Should not be accessible in Test Target
   func foo() {
   }
}
```

In Testing when @testable import it should not be available.

/**********
**UPDATE**
***********/

**Problem statement**

The Long param init method is used with convenience methods to provide default arguments but then in testing, I don't want to access that convenience method with the default argument because it's easy to forget to provide mock depedancy.

Comment: That's not possible. All internal methods are accessible when using `@testable import`. Why is it such a big problem if your test target has access to that specific method/init? Why can other types from your module access that init, but not test targets?

Comment: This is not worth putting a bounty on; you will be paying for the info you've already received. You either need to put the convenience initializers in another module or deal with the extra overloads.

Comment: The usual thing is the opposite, ie to make a private member public for purposes of testing. That's easy. The reverse is impossible and there is no good reason for it.

Comment: "but then in testing, I don't want to access that convenience method with the default argument because it's easy to forget to provide mock depedancy." Well _don't_ forget! Or else fix your dependency architecture.

Comment: @matt Can you please explain what you mean by Fixing the Dependency architecture?

Comment: I don't know what I mean because you didn't show any actual code. You have not said _anything_ about the real problem you're trying to solve. It's an X-Y question. As you've been told, you've just wasted 50 points of rep: throwing rep at the question doesn't improve it or change the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to do so.

1. You can add the following code in your `init`

```swift
#if DEBUG
if let _ = NSClassFromString("XCTest") {
    fatalError("Should not be used in unit test.")
}
#endif
```

With this solution, you can still use this `init` in your unit test, but it will crash at runtime.

2. Add a new configuration `Testing`, you can do this by `Select your debug config -> Click + -> Duplicate Debug`, and rename it to `Testing`
   [image]

then in your main target, add a new flag `TESTING` in the config `Testing`.
[image]

Next go to `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme` Set build configuration to `Testing` for your `Test`
[image]

Finally add this around your `init`.

```swift
#if !TESTING
init() {}
#endif
```

Now, you should not be able to use this `init` in your unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Mark that function as `Private`. Then it will not be available in test target.

You cannot access private entities from another module and this also applies to test targets. That is what access control is for.

Answer (score 0):

You could just `import` the module as opposed to `@testable import`.